# How to increase efficiency using group by and mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am currently experiencing an exponential increase in time it takes to perform a command using tidyverse package.

Consider the following structure (simplified):

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
              ID =c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
              sales = c(100, 250, 300, 50, 600, 390),
              t   = c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.05,0.15,0.2),
              n=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
              correct_result = c(-221.4,-27.8,69.1,-143.71,-19.11,43.19))
```

data$ID <- as.integer(data$ID)

I found that it is more efficient to group by ID as integer, rather than factor.

The formula I am trying to calculate implies that for a given name, say, "a", I want to take the sum of sales of all other related names (by their ID) and divide by 1-t for the respective names.
To get a sense of what I am trying to compute for each ID & and name:

```
(data$sales[2]/(1-data$t[2]))*(data$t[1]-data$t[2]) + (data$sales[3]/(1-data$t[3]))*(data$t[1]-data$t[3])
(data$sales[1]/(1-data$t[1]))*(data$t[2]-data$t[1]) + (data$sales[3]/(1-data$t[3]))*(data$t[2]-data$t[3])
(data$sales[1]/(1-data$t[1]))*(data$t[3]-data$t[1]) + (data$sales[1]/(1-data$t[1]))*(data$t[3]-data$t[1])
```

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
# The Model:
    data <- data %>%
  mutate(ovt=sales/(1-t))

sumforgoup1 <-function(forname , groupid){   # Create the function: 
  
  key_t <- dplyr::filter(data,
                         ID == groupid,
                         name==forname) %>% pull(t)
  
  temp <- dplyr::filter(data,
                        ID == groupid,
                        name!=forname) %>% mutate(diff_key_t=
                                                    key_t - t)
  
  sum(temp$ovt*temp$diff_key_t)
}

mutate(rowwise(data),
       result = sumforgoup1(name,ID))          # Store result in a new column.
```

So, the function works fine in this dataset. However, when i apply this function over a larger dataset with, say, 300 rows, the formula takes approximately 6 seconds. Increasing the number of rows with 300 more (i.e., 600 rows) it takes around 35 seconds..
I have around 30.000 rows, so this would take hours..

In the full dataset i converted ID to factor so you can get a sense of the levels (sub here = name):

```
$ ID   : Factor w/ 9097 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ sub  : Factor w/ 40 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

Any recommendations/tips is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Another good tip is to use dtplyr (is there a reason for people to keep using dplyr instead of dtplyr?) or data.table. The speed improvement is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is slow because filtering the data repeatedly introduces a lot of overhead that isn't necessary.  Instead you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(result = map_dbl(seq_along(ID), ~ sum((sales[-.x] / (1 - t[-.x]) * (t[.x] - t[-.x])))))

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   ID [2]
  name     ID sales     t     n correct_result   ovt result
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         1   100  0.1      1         -221.  111.  -221. 
2 b         1   250  0.3      2          -27.8 357.   -27.8
3 c         1   300  0.4      3           69.1 500     69.0
4 d         2    50  0.05     1         -144.   52.6 -144. 
5 e         2   600  0.15     2          -19.1 706.   -19.1
6 f         2   390  0.2      3           43.2 488.    43.2
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!
After weeks with frustration it was good to get the answer.